# Cannot getting a storage variable from another contract using inline-assembly

Tags: solidity, assembly, yul

I am trying to develop myself on inline-assembly. There are two contracts: CryptoDevs and Whitelist. In the assembly, i copied the whole code of whitelist contract instance into cryptodevs memory. What I am trying to achieve is to get the value of the maxWhitelistedAddresses value in the whitelist contract using inline-assembly. Thanks in advance.

```
contract CryptoDevs {

   // Whitelist contract instance
    Whitelist whitelist;

    // Number of tokens reserved for whitelisted members
    uint256 public reservedTokens;
    uint256 public reservedTokensClaimed = 0;


    /**
      * @dev ERC721 constructor takes in a `name` and a `symbol` to the token collection.
      * name in our case is `Crypto Devs` and symbol is `CD`.
      * Constructor for Crypto Devs takes in the baseURI to set _baseTokenURI for the collection.
      * It also initializes an instance of whitelist interface.
      */
constructor (address whitelistContract) ERC721("Crypto Devs", "CD") {
        assembly {
            // load free memory pointer
            let ptr := mload(0x40)
            // retrieve the size of the code
            let size := extcodesize(whitelistContract)
            mstore(ptr, size)
            // copy the code of whitelist contract
            extcodecopy(whitelistContract, add(ptr, 0x20), 0, size)
            // get the code from memory
            let code := mload(0x40)
            // store the code in storage
            sstore(0x02, code)
        }
    }
```

and this is the original code I am trying to turn into assembly.

```
contract CryptoDevs {

    // Whitelist contract instance
    Whitelist whitelist;

    // Number of tokens reserved for whitelisted members
    uint256 public reservedTokens;
    uint256 public reservedTokensClaimed = 0;

    /**
      * @dev ERC721 constructor takes in a `name` and a `symbol` to the token collection.
      * name in our case is `Crypto Devs` and symbol is `CD`.
      * Constructor for Crypto Devs takes in the baseURI to set _baseTokenURI for the collection.
      * It also initializes an instance of whitelist interface.
      */
    constructor (address whitelistContract) ERC721("Crypto Devs", "CD") {
        whitelist = Whitelist(whitelistContract);
        reservedTokens = whitelist.maxWhitelistedAddresses();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to copy the code of one contract into the other like that. You can't read state variables like that.

If you already have the `whitelist` address, you can do:

```
contract CryptoDevs {

    // Whitelist contract instance
    Whitelist whitelist;

    // Number of tokens reserved for whitelisted members
    uint256 public reservedTokens;
    uint256 public reservedTokensClaimed = 0;

    constructor (address whitelistContract) ERC721("Crypto Devs", "CD") {
        bytes4 selector = bytes4(keccak256("maxWhitelistedAddresses()"));

        assembly {
            let ptr := mload(0x40)

            // store the whitelist
            sstore(whitelist.slot, whitelistContract)

            // call
            mstore(ptr, selector)
            let returnPtr := add(ptr, 0x20)
            let success := staticcall(gas(), whitelistContract, ptr, 0x4, returnPtr, 0x20)

            // revert if fail
            if iszero(success) {
                returndatacopy(0, 0, returndatasize())
                revert(0, returndatasize())
            }

            // save return value to storage
            let returnValue := mload(returnPtr)
            sstore(reservedTokens.slot, returnValue)

            // move free memory pointer
            mstore(0x40, add(ptr, 0x40))
        }
    }
}
```